# Alternative approach to strip symbols in a string

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a function which retains symbols that is inside of a word(a word can consist of a-zA-Z,0-9 and _), but removes every other symbol outside the word:

```
For example: 
Input String - hell_o ? my name _ i's <hel'lo/>
Output - ['hell_o' ,'my', 'name', '_', "i's" ,'hel'lo']
```

The function i am using :

```
l = ' '.join(filter(None,(word.strip(punctuation.replace("_","")) for word in input_String.split())))
l = re.sub(r'\s+'," ",l)
t = str.split(l.lower())
```

I know this is not the best, optimal way!!Does anyone recommend any alternatives that i can try??Probably a regEx to do this??

- I tried using:
  negative look around and look behinds: `\W+(?!\S*[a-z])|(?<!\S)\W+`
- `s.strip(punctuation)`
- `re.sub('[^\w]', ' ', doc.strip(' ').lower())` - This Removes punctuation inside the word too

Comment: If *you* know that this is not the ```best, optimal``` way then you must have some alternatives in mind - please list those (in the question) and the reasons you reject them so we know what not to work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match any character different than `a-zA-Z, 0-9 and _` as you mention, between 2 letters with `(?<=[a-z])\W(?=[a-z])` and replace it with nothing, to remove it.

In the end you will have a very dangerous algorithm for instance in the sentence `I'm fine.And you?` if there is no space after the dot it will end up in `I'm fineAnd you?` which may not be what you want.

---

**[EDIT]** after your comments.

Ok I misunderstood your question.

Now I came along with the one regex you want to select `'hell_o' ,'my', 'name', "i's" ,'hel'lo'`:

`(?<![a-z])[a-z][^\s]*[a-z](?![a-z])`.

You can see it working here: https://regex101.com/r/EAEelq/3. (don't forget the `i` and `g` flags).

---

**[EDIT]** As you also want to match the `_` outside a word

ok so if you want the underscores to be matched also update as is: `(?<![a-z_])[a-z_][^\s]*[a-z_](?![a-z_])|(?<= )[a-z_](?= )`.

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/EAEelq/4

Comment: Yeah!!Thanks for the suggestion!!But this regex doesn't solve the purpose!!I tried it with few examples!!But din't work as expected. For example : the input string is ` Hi there! don't d???o <this _? It ain't fun!!` and the expected output is `["hi" , 'there', 'don't' , 'd???o' , 'this' , '_', 'it' ,'ain't', 'fun']`. I am still trying for an alternative!!  Wondering if regEx is definitely a better alternative!!

Comment: I meant if regEx is the  `only`  better approach than what i have already done!!

Comment: I edited my response after your comments please check if it is what you want!

Comment: The regex has definitely given me a great start!!Thank you so much!!I am making few edits to the regex!!For Example:    `_?`   returns   `_?`, but i should return    `_` because     `?` is outside the word!!!

Comment: I edited the answer to match underscores as well outside words.